# Storing MemoryStream in Cache

Tags: c#, idisposable

I've come across this code in one of my projects, which has a static function to return a MemoryStream from a file, which is then stored in Cache. Now the same class has a constructor which allows to store a MemoryStream in a private variable and later use it. So it looks like this:

```
private MemoryStream memoryStream;

public CountryLookup(MemoryStream ms)
{
    memoryStream = ms;
}

public static MemoryStream FileToMemory(string filePath)
{
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    ReadFileToMemoryStream(filePath, memoryStream);

    return memoryStream;
}
```

Usage:

```
Context.Cache.Insert("test",
                CountryLookup.FileToMemory(
                    ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["test"]),
                new CacheDependency(someFileName)
                );
```

And then:

```
CountryLookup cl = new CountryLookup(
                ((MemoryStream)Context.Cache.Get("test"))
                );
```

So I was wondering who should dispose the memoryStream and when? Ideally CountryLookup should implement IDisposable.

Should I even care about it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's slightly ugly - in particular, the `MemoryStream` is stateful, because it has the concept of the "current position".

Why not just store a byte array instead? You can easily build multiple MemoryStreams which wrap the same byte array when you need to, and you don't need to worry about the statefulness.

MemoryStreams don't *usually* require disposal, but I personally tend to dispose them out of habit. If you perform asynchronous operations on them or use them in remoting, I believe disposal *does* make a difference at that point. Byte arrays are just simpler :)

Comment: +1, to store the `byte[]` array in the cache - instance members of `MemoryStream` are not guaranteed to be thread safe.